# Return true if bdays is today or in range of next 7 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I tried not to use in project any vendor libraries (excluding jquery) and faced a problem with checking who has a birthday today or in next 7 day

Is it quite easy to get who has bday today, but what is the condition for future days?

```
add_days: (date, days)->
 console.log "Old date", date.getDate()
 new_date = new Date()
 new_date.setTime(date + (days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)))
 console.log "New date", date.getDate()
 return new_date

bday_in_days: (bday, last_name)->
 today             = new Date()
 today_day         = Number today.getDate()
 today_month       = Number today.getMonth() + 1
 today_year        = Number today.getFullYear()

 bday_gen_splitter = bday?.split(".")
 bday_gen_day      = Number bday_gen_splitter?[0]
 bday_gen_month    = Number bday_gen_splitter?[1]
 bday_gen_year     = Number bday_gen_splitter?[2]
 bday_gen_year     = today_year unless bday_gen_year
 bday_gen_date     = new Date("#{bday_gen_year}-#{bday_gen_month}-#{bday_gen_day}")

 bday_day         = Number bday_gen_date.getDate()
 bday_month       = Number bday_gen_date.getMonth() + 1
 @add_days(bday_gen_date, 2)

 cond_today    =  bday_day == today_day && bday_month == today_month
 cond_tomorrow =  bday_day == today_day - 1 && bday_month == today_month

 return cond_today || cond_tomorrow
```

Comment: can compare data objects directly... see if it is >= today and < 8 days from now

Answer (score 0):

The javacsript Date object has some useful method, such as getDate() and setDate(). My idea is to use this methods to define a new Date instance 7 days in the future. like `var futureDay = new Date(); futureDay.setDate(futureDay.getDate() + 7)`. This approach avoid having to deal with the months's end, it will automatically go to the next month if you increment its last day (30/31).

Another useful method is the getTime(). This will retrieve the time in miliseconds so you can use it to compare the current and the future dates with an arbitrary given date.

See the code below as a complete example. I hope it helps!

```
<script>

    function isValidBDay(day, month){

        var daysInTheFuture = 7;

        var today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0);
        today.setMinutes(0);
        today.setSeconds(0);
        today.setMilliseconds(0);

        var futureDay = new Date();
        futureDay.setDate(futureDay.getDate() + daysInTheFuture);

        var givenDay = new Date();
        givenDay.setDate(day);
        givenDay.setMonth(month - 1); // starts from 0

        return givenDay.getTime() >= today.getTime() && givenDay.getTime() <= futureDay.getTime();
    }

    alert(isValidBDay(7, 8)); // true since today is 31/07
    alert(isValidBDay(7, 12));// false;


</script>
```

Comment: Explaining a little bit what the code is doing is always better.

Comment: Improved the answer with a bit of explanation